# presentModalViewController: how to interact with parent

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

Showing a modal ViewController works fine:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myView];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
```

In my modal view, I have a navigation button to switch back to the mainmenu. Normally a would call `[self.navigationController popToViewController:delegate.viewMainmenu animated:YES];` but thats not possible inside the modal view. How can I interact with the "parent" to call him that he calls `popToViewController`?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8744062/1092219

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use property parentViewController in your modal vc and call 
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Comment: Thank you! With dismissModalViewController I can close the modal view, but how can I navigate to my mainmenu?

Comment: Well, if your main menu is the root vc, then just do popToRootViewController. Another option: make your main menu as singleton (cause it's usually only one per app) and access is like [MainMenu sharedMenu]. Then you can do smth like [self.navigationController popToViewController: [MainMenu sharedMenu]]

Comment: "self.navigationController popToViewController" doesn't work in the modal dialog, it only works in the parent. I try

Comment: of course it doesn't work :) that's because your modal view controller wasn't push into the navigation stack. 1. dismiss modal. 2. call pop in your parent

Comment: or try self.parentViewController.navigationController popToViewController"

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME: 1. save the parent-navigationController in the modal view 2. call "[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];" in the modal view 3. call "[navParent popToViewController:delegate.viewMainmenu animated:YES];" in the modal view (navParent is the parent-navigationController that I saved in the view)

Comment: This is no longer valid as of iOS 5.0, check this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/parentViewController

In short, now you have to use presentingViewController

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to dismiss the modal view controller, you'll want the modal view itself to call:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, dismissModalViewController closes the modal view, but I want to pop some views to go to my mainmenu.